# How to make a web service call (to Cognitive Services) from within Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services, azure-blob-storage

I have been trying to make a call to Cognitive Services from within Azure Functions without much luck. I have a Blob Triggered Function, which starts when an object is added to the blob. I wanted to output something to another blob container within the same Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this in the following way

1. Created a Function app (Blob Triggered) with the following bindings:

   ```
   "bindings": [
   {
     "name": "myBlob",
     "type": "blobTrigger",
     "direction": "in",
     "path": "originals/{name}",
     "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
   },
   {
     "type": "blob",
     "name": "outputBlob",
     "path": "extracted/processed-{name}.json",
     "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
     "direction": "out"
   }
   ], "disabled": false
   ```
2. Used the following code:

   ```
   #r "Newtonsoft.Json"

   using System;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Net.Http;
   using System.Net.Http.Headers;
   using Newtonsoft.Json;


   public static async Task Run(Stream myBlob, Stream outputBlob, TraceWriter log)
   {
    string subscriptionKey = "YOUR KEY HERE";
    string uriBase = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/recognizeText";

    int ID = 0;
    String outputJSON = "json string to be written onto blob";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

    string requestParameters = "handwriting=true";
    string uri = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    string operationLocation = null;
    HttpContent content = new StreamContent(myBlob);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       operationLocation = response.Headers.GetValues("Operation-Location").FirstOrDefault();
    else
    {
       log.Info("\nError:\n");
       log.Info((await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()));
       return;
     }

     string contentString;
     ...
     ...
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
     response = await client.GetAsync(operationLocation);
     contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     RootObject jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(contentString);

     log.Info(outputJSON); // at this point outputjson has the info needed to write onto the new blob

     byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outputJSON);
     outputBlob.Write(data,0,data.Length);
   }
   ```

I hope this helps. Cheers! :)

Comment: Great, you could accept your answer to close this question.

Comment: Sure. I just have to wait until tomorrow per SO rules. :)